# Call a JS function from HTML inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick, addition

I am trying to join three languages with no luck. 

I need to call javascript function to add clicked text to textarea, which is inside php with html.

This is what I tried as my best with no luck:

```
$hint .= "<br>" . "<a href='#' onclick='addtext(". $name .")'> " . $name . " </a> ";
```

I think I need somehow to echo that $name inside addtext() function, but don't know how, because I can't write statement inside another. I think so, because when I debug code, I see that this is recognized not as string but as attribute property:

[image]

JS function:

```
function addtext(str) {
    var newtext = str;
    document.getElementById("msg").value += newtext;
}
```

Please suggest a working solution to this problem.

Comment: What does a string need to be surrounded by in order to be recognized as a string?

Comment: I can't get it to work because my quotes get different when I surround it:
$hint .= "<br>" . "<a href='#' onclick='addtext('". $name ."')'> " . $name . " </a> ";

<a href="#" onclick="addtext(" kokių dokumentų reikia gamybinei praktikai atlikti?')'> Kokių dokumentų reikia gamybinei praktikai atlikti? </a>

Answer (score 0):

Put your string inside function with quotation marks ;)

Comment: Please write me how it must look like, because it doesn't go with added single quotes..

Comment: $hint .= "<br>" . "<a href='#' onclick=\"addtext('". $name ."')\"> " . $name . " </a> "; - should work

Comment: I made it in a simpler way:
$hint .= '<br>' . '<a href="#" onclick="addtext(this)">' . $name . '</a> ';
 and js function was edited to: function addtext(link) {
 var newtext = link.innerHTML;